# Already have an app-id. How to register app in Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, app-id

I have been using the auto generated facebook app-id for some time in my website. I had no knowledge of the App registration page back then. Is there any way I can still register my website in facebook using the app-id that I currently use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get the app-id already, there is already an fb app registered and you don't need to register it again.

to link up your  website w/ the app-id, simply go to fb dev app (https://developers.facebook.com/apps), set the site URL of the app to match w/ your website

Comment: Thanks Eddy. I had not officially registered my app previously. Because I was logged in to Facebook, they already had some credentials and gave me an appid whenever I got the code for like button. After accessing the URL you mentioned above, I was able to rename the Unnamed app as I wanted. Thanks !